# Rails 4 : Table Boolean Column Update Using "link_to "with a specific value "TRUE" always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my customer controller the update method code is like bellow:

```
  def update
    @customer= Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
      redirect_to  customers_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

In my view in customers index page I am planning to add a "link_to" link, if it is clicked, then that particular customers field "doc_delete" should be updated with value "TRUE".

```
<td><%= link_to "[Update", *************what is here ?******** method: :put %></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass hidden params through [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

```
<%= button_to "Update", user, method: :put, params: { doc_delete: true } %>
```

This will create a micro-form, much like what `Marwen` alluded to. Whilst quite inefficient, it will be the best way to send data to your `update` action.

--

Another, more efficient, way would be to define a custom route/action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do
   patch :doc_delete, on: :member #-> url.com/users/:id/doc_delete
end

#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def doc_delete
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
      redirect_to customers_path if @customer.update doc_delete: true
   end
end

#app/views/customers/index.html.erb
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
   <%= link_to "Update", customer_doc_delete_path(customer) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you rich, what about doing it the way in the answer I posted ? Is it good doing that way ?

Comment: Yep, but you need to understand how you're passing the `doc_delete` attribute. You could do it through the link but it will be ugly: `link_to "Update", user_path(user, doc_delete: true), method: :patch`

Comment: Is it possible to pass params through link_to as you said like using button_to ?

Comment: No because `link_to` is an HTML link `<a href="...` whilst `button_to` creates a form (like what `@marwen` posted)

Comment: No problem, hope it helped you out some!

Comment: Definitely, improvising day per day the way I program :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a form to do that for you

```
<% unless customer.doc_delete? %>
  <%= form_for customer do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field_tag :doc_delete, true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Where to insert this form?

*Well if you are rendering you costumers using:*

```
   <%=render @costumers %>
```

then you will add the form in the `/customers/_customer.html.erb`

*If you are looping them manually:*

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%=customer.full_name %>
  ## Here you can add the form
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am inserting this link_to update in my customer index which lists a large number of customers, so will it affect if I insert this form to my index ?

Comment: You need to update a single `costumer` or all of them at once?

Comment: Thanks for the support buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

An another way, you can use ***Ajax***.

```
#app/views/customers/index.html.erb
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
   <% if !customer.doc_delete == true %>
     <%= link_to "Update", customer_doc_delete_path(customer), remote: true %>
   <% else %>
     <%= Updated %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

#config/routes.rb
resources :customers do
   patch :doc_delete, on: :member #-> url.com/customers/:id/doc_delete
end

#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def doc_delete
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]

      if @customer.update doc_delete: true
        respond_to do | format |  
          format.js {render :nothing => true} 
        end 
      end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**In my index.html**

```
      <td>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'delete_present', :value => "present" %>
        <%=link_to "[update]", customer_path(customer, :doc_delete => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
      </td>
```

**In my customer controller**

```
def update
      if params[:doc_delete].present?
        @customer= Customer.find(params[:id])
        @customer.doc_delete=true
        @customer.save
        redirect_to  customers_path
      else  
        @customer= Customer.find(params[:id])
        if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
          redirect_to  customers_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
  end
```